# Angular 2 Can't resolve all parameters for abcService

Tags: angularjs, angular, dependency-injection

Getting the following error message when trying to inject a config object into a service:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for abcService: (?, [object Object]).
```

I followed the documentation on [dependency injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens), but can't get it working.

In my service `abc.service.ts` I have the following:

```
import { IabcConfig } from 'abc.types';
export let ABC_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken('abc.config');

@Injectable()
export class abcService {
    private config: IabcConfig;    

    constructor(@Inject(ABC_CONFIG) config: IabcConfig, private http: Http) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

and in my module `abc.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IabcConfig } from '@abc/abc.types';
import { abcService, ABC_CONFIG } from '@abc/abc.service';

export const abcConfig: IabcConfig = {
    save: false,
    title: 'ABC',
}

@NgModule({ 
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
})
export class ABCModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [
                o7AuthenticationService,
                { provide: ABC_CONFIG, useValue: abcConfig },
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Important libs I am using:

```
angular@2.4.0
angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1
zone.js@0.7.4
```

Comment: in abc.service you have ABC_CONFIG exported and you do @Inject(AUTH_CONFIG), is it a rename error or a real mistake in your code?

Comment: Updated it, removed code in between and just renamed it for simplicity sake.

Comment: So after a suggestion I tried referencing the abc.service by using its relative path. Astoundingly this works, but is obviously not the correct way it should. BTW should probably mention abs.service is its own npm package. so relative path is 'node_modules/abc/abc.service'

Comment: are you using systemjs?

Comment: "Can't resolve all parameters for abcService ..." did you try to remove the other parameters ? are you sure ABC_CONFIG is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Add import for Angular's `HttpModule` in `ABCModule`.

```
....
@NgModule({ 
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule
    ]
})
```

### ...

Update: probably I misunderstood original code, but I still assume that angular cannot find/resolve `HTTP` that you use in `AbcService`'s constructor. Unless you didn't provide piece of code for that...

Comment: Not in this case, the HttpModule is found, as you can see the value injected is type [object Object], but the config object is a ? meaning it could not be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

So ends up that when using a custom npm package, with services that take injectable objects, at least in webpack.config.ts we had to add our custom package `@abc` under `externals: includeClientPackages(/@angularclass|@angular|@abc)`

This fixed all the 'could not resolve parameter' errors